# How to create custom Textview for notification RemoteView

Tags: android, push-notification, android-custom-view

When I add custom `TextView` to layout for `RemoteViews`. It is generating following error.

> Exception - Bad notification posted from package Couldn't expand `RemoteViews`

For default `TextView` it is working properly.

```
RemoteViews notificationView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.news_article_notification_panel);    

     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal">

         <com.android.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_appname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="Univadis"
            android:textColor="@color/accent"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can't use custom `View`s in `RemoteViews`.

Comment: @MikeM. Any specific reason?

Comment: 'cause [they said so](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout). Seriously, tho, [Romain Guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298575/romain-guy) gives a reason in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752445/why-should-i-use-remoteviews-for-android-home-screen-widgets/5752457#comment6586115_5752457): "For security reasons. By using RemoteViews, we can ensure that an application will not execute code inside another process (Launcher for instance.) It is thus not possible to benefit from the privileges granted to the other process (Launcher.)"

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a Custom Views into a RemoteViews. RemoteViews is limited to a handful of possible widgets, specifically [these documented](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout) for use on a Notifications.

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.lokeshlabs.customviews.R;

public class MyButton extends AppCompatButton{

    private Context mContext;

    public MyButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }

    public void init(Context context){
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        if(isPressed())
            setBackgroundDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_pressed));
        else
            setBackgroundDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_released));
        setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#eceff1"));

        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

}
```

Identify like you did in xml